# Adding IF statement to DXL script to check object type?

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm currently working on a dxl script that exports to a .tex file which then uses TexWorks to format the export into a pdf. My issue currently is that both my tables and figures in DOORS are OLE objects. I was wondering if I can put an IF statement to distinguish between the two and how would I go about doing this? I'm not sure what the syntax is in DOORS DXL scripting for object type.

```
void writeFigureHeadAndExport(Stream& oss, Object img, string outputDir)
{
  if (o."Object Type""" == "Figure")
  {
   Module mod = module(img);   
   string n = mod."Prefix"img."Absolute Number"".png";
   string s = exportPicture(img, outputDir "\\" n, formatPNG);   
   oss << "\\begin{figure}[ht]\n";
   oss << "\\centering\n";
   oss << "\\includegraphics[width=\\textwidth]{"n"}\n";
   }

   else
   {
   Module mod = module(img);   
   string n = mod."Prefix"img."Absolute Number"".png";
   string s = exportPicture(img, outputDir "\\" n, formatPNG);   
   oss << "\\begin{table}[ht]\n";
   oss << "\\centering\n";
   oss << "\\includegraphics[width=\\textwidth]{"n"}\n";
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to discover the type of an Ole item, but it's very difficult to implement. I would suggest an additional attribute that specifies if an object has a table or a figure in it, then using that for the IF statement handling.

Comment: Thanks for the response Russell. As of currently, my DOORS module is configured where there is an attribute labeled "Object Type" that classifies the object text such as a table, figure, general text, or heading. Is this attribute not sufficient for the IF statement handling and I need another attribute to fully process the IF statement?

Comment: If that's the case, then you should be good to go! You'll probably want to expand the IF statement above into an IF(Figure) ELSE IF (TABLE) ELSE type, but it should otherwise work.